# HTML Nested Table Not Nesting

Tags: html, nested

I'm trying to make a nested table and its not working. It only works when I have a nested table following another table:

```html
  <table>
  </table>

    <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>C#</td>
                      <td>⭐⭐⭐⭐</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>MS SQL Server</td>
                      <td>⭐⭐⭐</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>HTML</td>
                    <td>⭐⭐</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>JavaScript</td>
                    <td>⭐⭐</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

But if I have just the nested table without the first empty table it doesn't nest:

```html
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>C#</td>
                  <td>⭐⭐⭐⭐</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>MS SQL Server</td>
                  <td>⭐⭐⭐</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>HTML</td>
                <td>⭐⭐</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>JavaScript</td>
                <td>⭐⭐</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Here I end up getting a table with 4 rows each with two columns.

Comment: Why do you need to nest the tables when you can just use one table?

Comment: I see a table with two rows and four columns in both cases in Safari on iOS...

Answer (score 0):

No need to use nested tables when you can use one table:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>C#</td>
        <td>⭐⭐⭐⭐</td>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>⭐⭐</td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>MS SQL Server</td>
        <td>⭐⭐⭐</td>
        <td>Javascript</td>
        <td>⭐⭐</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```